# How to install to current user path?

Tags: installation

I'm making an installer and I want it to extract to a specific user path like `C:\Current User\Documents`  with current user being the current user installing it. Anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing is to never hard-code a path like `C:\Current User\Documents` or `C:\Documents and Settings\username`, because the actual folder names will vary depending on the Operating System and language of the user's computer.

In most installers, you can use a pre-defined command-line variable for various OS defined folders. For example, the variable `%HOMEDRIVE%` points to the default driver letter such as C:\, and  `%HOMEPATH%` is usually the profile folder. So, on my computer,

```
%HOMEDRIVE%\%HOMEPATH% = C:\Users\username
```

The command-line variable `%USERPROFILE%` points to the same location. If you just need the username, use `%USERNAME%`.

If you are looking for the user's "My Documents" folder or other similar folders, you can get it from the registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders
```